# corrupting apk after proguard obfuscation

Tags: android, eclipse, proguard

I try to use proguard android tools. But obfuscated apk is not installed (i use eclipse export wizard). dex2jar show me that all classes were in jar but named with *.dump.txt and contains something like this:

```
//class:0002  access:0x0011
public final class com.company.android.BuildConfig
//field:0000  access:0x0019
//Lcom/company/android/BuildConfig;.DEBUG Z
public static final  Z DEBUG=true;

//method:0000  access:0x10001
//Lcom/company/android/BuildConfig;.<init>()V
public V <init>()
                this:v0   //com.company.android.BuildConfig
LOCAL_VARIABLE LL0 ~ LL1 v0 -> this // Lcom/company/android/BuildConfig; 
LABEL               |  LL0: line 4
INVOKE_DIRECT       |     |v0.<init>()  //Ljava/lang/Object;.<init>()V
RETURN_VOID         |     |return
LABEL               |  LL1:
```

Where i'm wrong? How can i make working obfuscating apk?

My proguard.cfg:

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

My project.properties:

```
target=android-8
proguard.config=proguard.cfg
```

Thanks!